# Are there any Jenkins plugins for Mercurial code review?

Tags: java, mercurial, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, gerrit

I wasn't able to find any Jenkins plugins for Mercurial code review. I've found separate plugins for Mercurial, but they don't seem to integrate with Jenkins.

Is there something like [Gerrit](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Gerrit+Trigger) but for Mercurial?

Answer (score 3):

Gerrit's older brother, Rietveld (https://code.google.com/p/rietveld/) supports:

- Mercurial (this is what you ask about)
- Git
- Subversion
- Perforce
- CVS

As far as I know, there is no Rietveld-Jenkins integration, but I believe it shouldn't be a big issue to add a such functionality to the tool. Rietveld provides basic, but sufficient API: https://code.google.com/p/rietveld/wiki/APIs which allows easy integration with Jenkins. Maybe not as feature rich like in the Gerrit case, but the basic functionality (gate-keeping) should be relatively easy to implement.